# Problem when using type Any for mutiple-dispatch in Julia

Tags: julia, any

I am trying to write a function that receives a tuple and a dictionary as arguments.

```
function findBestAction(state::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, qTable::Dict{Any, Matrix{Float64}})
   doSomething()
end
```

I want the function to receive dictionaries whose keys can be of any possible type. I run the following command but receive error messages:

```
findBestAction((0, 0), qTable) #qTable::Dict{String, Matrix{Float64}}
```

Error Messages:

```
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ e:\Master Thesis\lu_jizhou\Learning\q_learning.jl:33

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching findBestAction(::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, ::Dict{String, Matrix{Float64}})
Closest candidates are:
  findBestAction(::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, ::Dict{Any, Matrix{Float64}}) at e:\Master Thesis\lu_jizhou\Learning\q_learning.jl:33
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ e:\Master Thesis\lu_jizhou\Learning\q_learning.jl:48
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `Dict{String, ...)` is *not* a subtype of `Dict{Any, ...)`.

This is the way parametric types (i.e. types with other types in their curly braces) behave in Julia. From the Julia manual [section on Parametric types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-parametric-composite-types):

> ```
> julia> Point{Float64} <: Point{Real} 
> false
> ```
>
> *Warning*
>
> This last point is very important: even though `Float64 <: Real` we DO
> NOT have `Point{Float64} <: Point{Real}`.
>
> In other words, in the parlance of type theory, Julia's type
> parameters are invariant

You can instead write the function as

```
function findBestAction(state::Tuple{Int64, Int64}, qTable::Dict{<:Any, Matrix{Float64}})
   doSomething()
end
```

which explicitly says that any subtype of `Any` is allowed as the key type in the `Dict`.

You can also consider changing the `Dict` to an `AbstractDict`, and the value type of it  to be something like `<:AbstractMatrix{<:Real}`, if your code is written generically in a way that works for any `AbstractMatrix` and any `Real` subtype.